# How do I fit nested elements inside padded parents?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to nest a element inside of another, and then effectively have it have a border via padding (on the parent) / margin (on the child), but the element always extends outside of the element.

ex : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34916/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 content">
            <div>
            Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.bg {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.content {
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

How do I get the purple row to stay inside the green but also maintain the margin?

Comment: It seems to be working on the fiddle. Can you please put a screenshot of how it is being displayed for you ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bg {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
 color: white;
 background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 content">
    <div>
    Test
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Remove your margin in `.content` and add padidng in `.bg`